How to pick timestamps from ndarray if time() is bigger than 5:00
I have an ndarray of timestamps. I need to pick timestamps if they represent a time after 5:00.
The sample code is:
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

arr = np.array([1672713000, 1672716600, 1672720200, 1672723800, 1672727400, 1672731000])
threshold_time = datetime.strptime('5:00', '%H:%M').time()

new_arr = np.where(datetime.utcfromtimestamp(arr).time() > threshold_time)

However, when I try the following code, I get the this error:
TypeError: only integer scalar arrays can be converted to a scalar index

How to query ndarray correctly in this case? I can't use pandas to solve this issue.

Such solution worked for me:
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

arr = np.array([1672713000, 1672716600, 1672720200, 1672723800, 1672727400, 1672731000])
threshold_time = datetime.strptime('5:00', '%H:%M').time()

pick_time = np.vectorize(lambda x: datetime.utcfromtimestamp(x).time())

new_arr = np.where(pick_time(arr) > threshold_time)

print(arr[new_arr])

The output is:
[1672723800 1672727400 1672731000]


import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime

arr = np.array([1672713000, 1672716600, 1672720200, 1672723800, 1672727400, 1672731000])
threshold_time = datetime.strptime('5:00', '%H:%M').time()
func = np.vectorize(datetime.utcfromtimestamp)

# Create a boolean mask for accurate filtering
mask = (func(arr) > datetime.combine(datetime.today(), threshold_time)).astype(bool)

# Use the boolean mask to filter the array
new_arr = arr[mask]

print(new_arr)  # This will output the filtered timestamps

